# Problems with Foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

I'm working on a project to create an Ideas api, something like forum where people post ideas, and other people can comments, upvotes and downvotes.

I'm facing a problem with my DB and i dont know how to solve it.

The error is: `"update or delete on table \"idea\" violates foreign key constraint \"FK_861b419cce1c9ae64295300d6b6\" on table \"comment\"`

So as you guys can see on the error, i have a table called "idea" where i put the ideas and commentaries.

But this error occurs when i try to delete and Idea which has some commentary attached to it.

If i delete the idea without any commentaries, everything occurs fine.

But if the idea have a commentary attached to her, this error appers.

I searched a little online and some people said to me to put on my relations @OneToMany (one idea, many commentary) the { cascade: true }, but nothing happes.

I'm going to post how my entities are organized.

Just to clarify, I'm using NestJS framework with PostgreSQL as relational DB

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  JoinTable,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/user.entity';
import { IdeaEntity } from 'src/idea/idea.entity';

@Entity('comment')
export class CommentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;

  @Column('text')
  comment: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity)
  @JoinTable()
  author: UserEntity;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => IdeaEntity,
    idea => idea.comments,
  )
  idea: IdeaEntity;
}
```

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  CreateDateColumn,
  Column,
  ManyToOne,
  UpdateDateColumn,
  ManyToMany,
  JoinTable,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/user.entity';
import { CommentEntity } from 'src/comment/comment.entity';

@Entity('idea')
export class IdeaEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated: Date;

  @Column('text')
  idea: string;

  @Column('text')
  description: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    type => UserEntity,
    author => author.ideas,
  )
  author: UserEntity;

  @ManyToMany(type => UserEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  upvotes: UserEntity[];

  @ManyToMany(type => UserEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinTable()
  downvotes: UserEntity[];

  @OneToMany(
    type => CommentEntity,
    comment => comment.idea,
    { cascade: true },
  )
  comments: CommentEntity[];
}
```

edit1: I put a catch everything, to see more about this error, and This is what my terminal is showing

```
error: error: update or delete on table "idea" violates foreign key constraint "FK_861b419cce1c9ae64295300d6b6" on table "comment"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/gabriel/Desktop/Token/ideas-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:614:13)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/gabriel/Desktop/Token/ideas-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:413:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/gabriel/Desktop/Token/ideas-api/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:129:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 325,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23503',
  detail: 'Key (id)=(9452b702-e7e8-4585-adf7-ee84d16306cb) is still referenced from table "comment".',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'comment',
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: 'FK_861b419cce1c9ae64295300d6b6',
  file: 'ri_triggers.c',
  line: '3280',
  routine: 'ri_ReportViolation'
}
[Nest] 25768   - 03/28/2020, 4:28:40 PM   {"code":500,"timestamp":"2020-03-28T19:28:40.221Z","path":"/idea/9452b702-e7e8-4585-adf7-ee84d16306cb","method":"DELETE","message":"update or delete on table \"idea\" violates foreign key constraint \"FK_861b419cce1c9ae64295300d6b6\" on table \"comment\""} +12315ms
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cascade` property that you set here is intended for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations, as explained in the documentation of the property:

```js
/**
 * Sets cascades options for the given relation.
 * If set to true then it means that related object can be allowed to be inserted or updated in the database.
 * You can separately restrict cascades to insertion or updation using following syntax:
 *
 * cascade: ["insert", "update"] // include or exclude one of them
 */
```

The property which would allow you to do this cascade `DELETE` is `onDelete` set to `CASCADE`:

```js
/**
 * Database cascade action on delete.
 */
onDelete?: OnDeleteType;
```

With `OnDeleteType` being:

```js
/**
 * ON_DELETE type to be used to specify delete strategy when some relation is being deleted from the database.
 */
export declare type OnDeleteType = "RESTRICT" | "CASCADE" | "SET NULL" | "DEFAULT" | "NO ACTION";
```

**However**, cascade deletion has always been a tedious topic in TypeORM (you can see multiple issues on the GitHub project). I assume this was working well with ManyToMany, but depending on the version you're using, I cannot guarantee the result...